# How can I navigate from my current position to a specific point with OpenStreetMap data under Android?

Tags: openstreetmap, android, navigation

How can I navigate from my current position to a specific point, using OpenStreetMap data, running on Android? 
I also want to get updated current points until reaching the final point then navigation stops.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inclined to set up your own server for the area you're interested in routing within, you can check out the open-source [OpenTripPlanner (OTP)](http://www.opentripplanner.org/) project for multimodal trip planning.  OTP uses OpenStreetMap data for car/bike/pedestrian routing, and [General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS)](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) data for transit data.

We've developed an open-source [OpenTripPlanner Android client](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki), which is also available [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.usf.cutr.opentripplanner.android).

Answer (score 0):

The only OSM routing I've performed was using pgRouting. This is an extension for PostGIS. I found it a bit cumbersome to use. However, assuming you don't want to write your own algorithm, then this is going to have to be one of the options to consider. You would have to implement it on a server and then your android device communicate to the server.

I don't know which country you're in, but the US-wide OSM street data is also quite large. Something to bare in mind if you want to run it locally.